# Throw exception when trying to get icon from package name

Tags: java, android, sockets, package-name, application-icon

I am trying to get an icon from a package name. The package name is getting passed to me through a socket. I am getting the package name and trying to use it to get the icon, but it is throwing an exception. I never get the print statement for the icon. Any ideas why?

```
           try  {

              Socket socket = new Socket("192.170.10.15", 5050);


              DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


              String packagename = DIS.readUTF();
              System.out.println("package name" + packagename);


              Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packagename);
              System.out.println("icon" + icon);


              socket.close();


           } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Did not receive string");
           }
```

The exception that is getting thrown is this: my exception now, when I want the icon for "Iso Mounter" app, is:

```
Exception is android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.iso.mounter –
```

Comment: Typically when exceptions are thrown, they're thrown to tell you what the problem is. For us to help debug this problem we'll need to know what exception is being thrown.

Comment: @CanadianCoder The exception being thrown is just the "catch" statement I have, which I set to print "Did not receive string". And this gets catch gets printed before "icon" prints, so I know the issue is with Drawable icon. Maybe there is a better way I can debug to see what the issue is?

Comment: Try to print the exception like this : catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Exception is "+e.toString());
           }

Comment: @WannaBeGeek Thank you! That is very helpful. my exception now, when I want the icon for "Iso Mounter" app, is: Exception is android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.iso.mounter

Comment: Do you have package named "com.iso.mounter" in your app ?

Comment: @WannaBeGeek I realized that I don't have that package name in my app... So I will work on that.